# Rails AJAX calls to update current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have a grid style card layout on a page of my site. I have a set of filter options just above it. Currently when the filters are used, Rails uses the `data-remote="true"` attribute to call a controller action that gets the correct new data and runs the associated JS based view.

Here's an example of the JS view:

```
<%
  cars = render partial: 'garages/cars/car', collection: @cars
  paginator = paginate(@cars, window: 1, outer_window: 2, remote: true)
  pagination_info = page_entries_info @cars
%>

function updateContent() {
  <% if (cars) %>
    $('.pagination').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginator) %>');
    $('.pagination-info').html('<%= escape_javascript(pagination_info) %>');
    $('.load-more a').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(link_to_next_page @cars, "View more", remote: true, params: params) %>');

    //if (source == 'filters') {
      //$('.car-grid').html('<%= escape_javascript(cars) %>');
    //} else {
      $('.car-grid').html('<%= escape_javascript(cars) %>');
    //}
  <% end %>
}
```

I'm attempting to convert my app to solely use Webpacker but as these JS based view templates are not part of the compiled packs, they do not work.

Is there a way to make them work again OR do I have to do this sort of functionality a different way now and if so, what can you recommend?

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Pardon my naivety but is this really how Rails expects developers to use Webpack? This can't be right way to do it, can it?

Comment: @JoshBrody I basically want to incorporate the above functionality into Webpack using Webpacker. Currently the above doesn't work as it's not a part of my JS pack. But I can't move it to be so becuase then the view file would not be found. I need to know if there is a way to get this working or if i need to go about it in an entirely different way.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use a Javascript templating library and a JSON endpoint?

Comment: @JoshBrody I would do, the listings I can do like that no problem but as in the OP above, I need to use some view helpers such as `pagination_info` which I can't use if i do it like that.   Any ideas?